# SSIS data from one table to another row by row by making it nto two rows with different computation in a SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I need to move data from one table to another in the same database using an SSIS package, The data from source table is taken and it is computed to form two rows differently and load it into destination table.

I prefer using a stored procedure for this. Kindly help me out here..

Comment: Please elaborate as what are the src and target table structure and what transformations you want to apply.

Comment: Can you be more specific in your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure to copy data from one table to another:

```
CREATE MyStoredProcedure AS
INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM TABLE2
```

Now put this in an execute SQL Task inside your SSIS:

```
 EXEC MyStoredProcedure
```

Now consider whether you need the overhead of a SSIS package to do this when you can just run it in a SQL step in a SQL Agent job.